Keras metrics do not work with custom loss function
I am working on a neural network model with keras.
My y values have a shape like: (..., 2)
So my y_pred is going to have the same shape.
The problem is that the values of y represent a range of values that could be true (for example in row 1 all values between 1 and 2 are acceptable).
In my custom function I need to check if the absolute value of those 2 y_pred values is between the range indicated by y_true and if it is then my loss would be 0.
If it is not in the range, then I would calculate the deviation of the value predicted by the network from the nearest end.
For example, let's say that my y_true= [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
and my y_pred = [[1.5, 1.7], [2.3, 3.4], [7, 10]]
Then the absolute values of y_pred would be = [1.6, 2.85, 8.5]
So, in the end for row 0, my loss would be 0 (cause 1<1.6<2 )
for row 1, my loss would be 0 (cause 2.3<2.85<3.4 )
for row 2, my loss would be 4.5 (cause 4 < 8.5 ) and 8.5-4 = 4.5
Firstly, I tried to implement this thought with a for loop but keras does not like that.
Then I tried to do it with keras backend functions like tf.abs and tf.where but I did not make anything solid.
UPDATE
I searched more about tensorflow functions and I made this:
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_average = tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    
    # Geta lower and upper bounds from y_true
    y_true_lower = y_true[:, 0:1]
    y_true_upper = y_true[:, 1:]
    
    # Check if y_pred_average values are within the range defined by y_true_lower and y_true_upper
    within_range_lower = y_true_lower <= y_pred_average
    within_range_upper = y_pred_average <= y_true_upper
    within_range = tf.logical_and(within_range_lower, within_range_upper)
    
    loss_within_range = tf.zeros_like(y_pred_average)
    loss_outside_range = tf.reduce_min(tf.stack([tf.abs(y_pred_average - y_true_lower), tf.abs(y_pred_average - y_true_upper)], axis=-1), axis=-1)
    
    loss = tf.where(within_range, loss_within_range, loss_outside_range)
    
    return loss

the above function, when run it returns a 2d array of losses
The problem is that metrics do not return anything.
Accuracy is always 0 and mse is always nan
example when run:
y_t = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
])

y_p = np.array([
    [1.2, 1.5],
    [4.5, 4.7],
    [3.6, 4.8]
])

custom_loss_func(y_true=y_t, y_pred=y_p)

returned:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0. ],
       [0.6],
       [0.8]])>

I am probably doing something wrong. Or my thought process is wrong overall

I've tryed to reproduce youre experiment as follows:
y_t = tf.constant(np.array([
[1, 2],
[3, 4],
[5, 6]
]), dtype=tf.float32)

y_p = tf.Variable(np.array([
    [1.2, 1.5],
    [4.5, 4.7],
    [3.6, 4.8]
]), dtype=tf.float32)


losses = []
x = tf.Variable(3.0)
for _ in range(200):
    with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(y_p)
        loss = custom_loss(y_true=y_t, y_pred=y_p)
    dy_dx = tape.gradient(loss, y_p)
    losses.append(loss.numpy().mean())
    y_p = y_p - dy_dx / 100.

plt.plot(losses)
plt.grid()

... and I had no problems with it:
Loss
But I suspect that using loss_within_range = tf.zeros_like(y_pred_average) as one of the components of the loss function is a bad idea. It is independent of y_pred (except its shape). If tf.where chooses its values as the final values for the loss function, then it will not be possible to calculate gradients.
